# Knockout - I want to set a value to dropdown after list loaded to the dropdown, not just by id, but as object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dropdown

I know you can set a value to dropdown using optionsValue, but without using it I want to set a value. Please look at this fiddle. I want to select the dropdown using an object instead of one property from the object.
here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1402/

Please help. Thanks.

Also the code:

```
var CountryModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
   self.countries = ko.observableArray([
        new CountryModel({id: "1", name: "Russia"}),
        new CountryModel({id: "2", name: "Qatar"})]);
    self.sendMe = function(){

        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice()}));
    };
    self.selectedChoice({id: "1", name: "Russia"});
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<br/>
```

And I want to set dynamically, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

In the **selectedChoice** observable you have to pass not an object with the same data, but the same instance from the countries array.

You can use that:

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
   // ...
   self.selectedChoice(self.countries()[0]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. but I want to dynamically set the object to the value.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?  You can use this technique to set the value to any element that's in the countries list.